# Minimal example of Katip logging library

Tags: haskell

Is there a minimal example demonstrating the use of [Katip logging library](https://github.com/Soostone/katip) for haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit goes to [Joe Kachmar](https://jkachmar.github.io)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}

module Main where

import Control.Exception
import Katip
import System.IO (stdout)

type Stack a = KatipContextT IO a

-- `Stack ()` is the same thing as `KatipContextT IO ()`
-- test :: Stack ()
test :: KatipContextT IO ()
test = do
  $(logTM) InfoS "Hello from Katip!"
  $(logTM) InfoS "I can do any kind of `IO` action here with `liftIO`!"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  handleScribe <- mkHandleScribe ColorIfTerminal stdout InfoS V2
  let mkLogEnv = registerScribe "stdout" handleScribe defaultScribeSettings =<< initLogEnv "MyApp" "production"

  bracket mkLogEnv closeScribes $ \le -> do
    runKatipContextT le (mempty :: LogContexts) mempty test
```